# Loop through an unspecified number of pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, cartesian-product

I have an n-number of pandas DataFrames each containing any number of elements, and I want produce all combinations that can be made by taking one element from each of the DataFrames.

Something like this, where I am showing three different DataFrames and I want to find the combinations that can be made only from column `'a'` from each:

```
Input:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]},{'b':[4,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7]},{'b':[4,4]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,5]},{'b':[4,4]})

Output:
1,7,1
1,7,5
2,7,1
2,7,5
```

I thought there might be a way to use nested for-loops but in not knowing the number of DataFrames, which may also be a large number, I'm not sure of how do that.

Comment: Are you looking for `itertools.product`?

Comment: That might work but I realize in simplifying my question I may have left out some important details; I'll revise.

Comment: So it looks like `for i in product(df1['a'],df2['a'],df3['a']):` will do the trick.